# Migrate Java EE service to Spring Boot Rest service

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

Im very new to JEE and monolithic applications.
I'm facing an architectural/concept problem while migrating a Java EE service to a Rest Spring Boot service. The Java EE service is part of a large monolithic business logic module.
The Goal is to incrementally migrate everything to spring boot, starting with my service.

Currently the rough scheme looks like this:

1. The function handling the logic of the service is invoked from yet another service. Lets say Service A invokes a function foo(param)  from service B
2. The Service B then stores the param in a csv and additionally returns the file using new File(name)

All of that is part of a batchProcess that is used for fileExports.

My current idea looks as follows:

1. In class A replace the invokation of B.foo(param) with a REST call. maybe not directly but through some service that implements a method to call the endpoint.
2. I would have my new Spring Service as a module to the current monolith. It would have regular endpoints to receive that param throug a POST call. Afterwards I would simply store it in a csv

Thats it.

My question for developing a high level concept of how to implement that would be:

1. Is the current JEE class A, that invokes the method of service class B a good place to add a call to a REST endpoint?
   My idea behind this is: Since I want to replace the rgular invokation of B.foo(param), I would rather make a  POST call to the REST endpoint, pass the param, and the Spring Boot services takes it and puts it in csv
2. What about dependencies? my current service class B has a couple of dependencies injected through @Inject. Is there anything apart from replacing @Inject with @Autowire, that I need to take care of?

What are your thoughts on this?